# Autoit replace string in multiple text files

Tags: windows, string, file, text, autoit

I have this code:

```
$szFile = "text.txt"
$szText = FileRead($szFile,FileGetSize($szFile))
$szText = StringReplace($szText, "before", "after")
FileDelete($szFile)
FileWrite($szFile,$szText)
```

It works but I have loads of text files to do this with and to configure the script each time is a problem. Does any one know how I could make it so it would do it for every file in that dir. I have tried `$szFile = "*.txt"` but that doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FileFindFirstFile](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileFindFirstFile.htm) supports wildcards. Note that the function returns a file handle which could then be used in your FileOpen call.